# Discord.py add content in a message

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have this code where I want it so that when I say `p!serverlist` it would print out the servers that it's in. I don't know how to "append" the servers in my variable a.

````py
if message.content.startswith('p!serverlist'):
        a = ''
        e = 0
        await message.channel.send('**Servers that I am in**')
        for guild in client.guilds:
            await a.append(f' `{guild.name}` ')
            e += 1
        await message.channel.send(a)
        await message.channel.send('**I am in ' + str(e) + ' servers!**')```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't `.append` it. You just use the `+=` operator.

```
a += f' {guild.name} '
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do u add something in front of `a`?

Comment: `a = "something" + a`